# Why is a GWT application crashing on blackberry OS7?

Tags: gwt, blackberry, crash, parseint

I tried the following code on a blackberry os7 browser:

```
<html>
<body>
test page
<script>
i = 0;
if(i < -2147483647) {
   alert("very low")
} 

if(i < -2147483648) {
   alert("very very low")
} 

if(i < -2147483649) {
    alert("very very very low")
}
</script></body></html>
```

And surprisingly it came out with very very low!!

I thought that integers in javascript were supposed to support more than that. Of course this code works well on other browsers...

The tricky thing is, I discovered that trying to run a gwt app on a blackberry. It worked fine on OS6 but not on OS7. I debugged my code compiled by GWT and it happens that the javascript implementation of Integer.parseInt has a test using the extreme high and extreme low of an int. As OS7 browser doesn't seem to support those extreme values properly (bit overflow?) I get an exception and my app doesn't start...

I'm trying to find a solution for that. I'm thinking about rewriting the GWT integer.parseInt implementation just for blackberry. what do you think? Any other ideas?

Comment: maybe rebinding would be an elegant solution, maybe with an own property provider - what's the browser permutation used by os7?

Comment: This is actually a webkit based browser so, it's the safari permutation I guess. We're looking at rebinding the integer.parseInt() method in GWT but we haven't found the way yet. Rebinding is an elegant workaround that's for sure. I'll post the solution if we found something.

Comment: ah, normal rebinding doesn't work because you can't extend Integer and parseInt is static, right? there would be another solution: gwt super-sourcing. BUT, that would require you to implement ALL functions and fields of Integer. and it gets even more complex if  you want to serialize it (in async calls, for example). and rebinding still isnt possible, so the new class is used by all permutations. if wanted, i'll gladly give you more infos about that, but that is really the last ray of hope.

Comment: The solution that we found so far is to actually avoid using integer.parseInt. This solution is not acceptable in the long run but it allows us to release our product for blackberry. Maybe we can  write a sort of utility method to call instead of calling parseInt in our code. I hope RIM is aware of that and I hope they'll fix it asap...

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles upon this old thread in search for answers:

It seems to me the bug is in the compiler part of the JS-engine.

Snippet 1:

```
var i = 0;
if (i < -2147483648) {
  console.log("less");
} else {
  console.log("greater");
}
```

Snippet 2:

```
var i = 0;
var j = i < -2147483648;
if (j) {
  console.log("less");
} else {
  console.log("greater");
}
```

While snippet 1 displays the bug by logging "less", snippet 2 does not.

So to get around the bug, we checked out the GWT sources and compiled our own SDK with this patch applied. We haven't had problems with Integer.parseInt since.

```
diff --git a/gwt240/source/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/lang/Number.java         b/gwt240/source/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/lang/Number.java
index 04a85e1..abb3e5c 100644
--- a/gwt240/source/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/lang/Number.java
+++ b/gwt240/source/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/lang/Number.java
@@ -221,9 +221,10 @@ public abstract class Number implements Serializable {
     }

     int toReturn = __parseInt(s, radix);
+    boolean isTooLow = toReturn < lowerBound;
     if (__isNaN(toReturn)) {
       throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
-    } else if (toReturn < lowerBound || toReturn > upperBound) {
+    } else if (isTooLow || toReturn > upperBound) {
       throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
     }
```

Link to GWT bug report: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7291